# QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component

Tags: qt, qml

i try to import(Cell.qml) in main.qml,but i'm getting this error:QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:4 "Cell.qml": no such directory

In our main QML file, we use our Cell component to create the color picker.
how can i fixed that?

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQml 2.0
import "Cell.qml"

Rectangle {
    id:page
    width:320;height: 480
    color: "lightgray"
    Text {
        id: helloText
        text: "Hello World";
        y:30
        anchors.horizontalCenter: page.horizontalCenter
        font.pointSize: 24; font.bold: true
    }
    Grid {
        id:colorPicker
        x:4;anchors.bottom: page.bottom;anchors.bottomMargin: 4
        rows: 2;columns: 3;spacing: 3

        Cell{cellColor: "red";onClicked: helloText.color=cellColor}
        Cell{cellColor: "green";onClicked: helloText.color=cellColor}
        Cell{cellColor: "blue";onClicked: helloText.color=cellColor}
        Cell{cellColor: "yellow";onClicked: helloText.color=cellColor}
        Cell{cellColor: "steelblue";onClicked: helloText.color=cellColor}
        Cell{cellColor: "black";onClicked: helloText.color=cellColor}
    }
}
```

Comment: you should not import a component, just use it in your code as `Cell {}`. The syntax you use is for folder content import. Read [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-imports.html#directory-imports) article for more help

Comment: thank for response,i did that but i get,qrc:/main.qml:28 Cell is not a type

Comment: @SamiraSarvi provide a [mre]

Comment: Did you add Cell.qml to the qrc file?

Comment: thanks, i add cell.qml in qrc file and then it work without import

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

- Add `Cell.qml` to your `qml.qrc` file.
- Import the ***directory*** of the `Cell.qml` file.  If `Cell.qml` is in relative directory `../foo/bar/widgets`:

  ```
  import '../foo/bar/widgets';
  ```

  *However*, if the file is already in the same directory as your `main.qml` file, then you do *not* need to import it.

*Note*: only `*.js` files are imported with a full path name. e.g.

```
import "../util/util.js" as Util;
```

Comment: thanks, it works with add in qml.qrc file,with import path didn't work

Comment: Great.  Then `Cell.qml` was in the directory of `main.qml`, right?